# Why are some coins partially frozen?

Tags: code-name-steam

During battles, some of the collectible appear partially frozen with ice on the top. What's the difference between the frozen and non-frozen coins?

[image: frozen coins]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Frozen coins are dropped by enemies, while non-frozen coins are out in the open or inside breakable crates. Both coin types function identically, giving 10 coins.